# Android: ParseException: Invalid Login Credentials

Tags: android, authentication, parse-platform, passwords

I am writing an `Android` app that registers a user into the `Parse` platform and allows a user to register and log in to the app. I can register users without any problem. However, when I check my _User table in Parse, it says that the password is undefined. Also, when I log in, it give shows me

-com.parse.ParseException: invalid login credentials

Here is the code for registering a user

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    //initialize parse with credentials
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignUpConfirm);
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
    ActionBar signUpActionBar = getActionBar();
    signUpActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));

}
public void registerUser(){
    getSignUpName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetSignUpName);
    getSignUpUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetSignUpUsername);
    getSignUpEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetSignUpEmail);
    getSignUpPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetSignUpPassword);
    getSignUpConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetSignUpConfirmPassword);
    signUpUsername = getSignUpUsername.getText().toString();
    signUpName = getSignUpName.getText().toString();
    signUpEmail = getSignUpEmail.getText().toString();
    signUpPassword = getSignUpPassword.getText().toString();
    signUpConfirmPassword = getSignUpConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
    newUser.setUsername(signUpUsername);
    newUser.setEmail(signUpEmail);
    newUser.put("fullName", signUpName);
    if(signUpPassword.equals(signUpConfirmPassword)){
    newUser.setPassword(signUpPassword);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                Intent finishRegistration = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
                startActivity(finishRegistration);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection to the server has failed.\n Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code for logging in a user

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ActionBar loginBar = getActionBar();
    loginBar.setTitle("Sign In");
    loginBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
    //initialize parse credentials
    Button logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignIn);
    logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logIn();
        }
    });

}
public void logIn(){
    getLoginUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetLoginUsername);
    getLoginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetLoginUsername);
    loginUsername = getLoginUsername.getText().toString();
    loginPassword= getLoginPassword.getText().toString();
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(loginUsername, loginPassword, new LogInCallback() {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                loginSuccessful();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Email/Password Combination", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
public void loginSuccessful(){
    Intent backToMainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
    startActivity(backToMainIntent);
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Add a log statement next to the below line and see if it is executed correctly.     newUser.setPassword(signUpPassword);

Comment: how would you log that? P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password value on the Parse dashboard is always undefined, to stop you being able to see what the users passwords are.

I think its not working because you have a bug in your login code.

```
getLoginUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetLoginUsername);
getLoginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eGetLoginUsername);
```

Both of these EditTexts are the same, even though one is for the password and the other the username. I'm guessing the ID for the password EditText is wrong.

Hope this helps.